# Extension host did not start in 10 seconds

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins

I using vs code to dev a plugin. using yo code tool generate a project. when i press F5 to run this plugin, error cannot running and debug plugin.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wKfc.jpg)

- vs code version:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cqrE.png)

i also using the latest stable version: 1.5.9, the same error.

### who known how to resolve this problem.